# Unable to activate concurrent-ruby-ext-1.1.3, because concurrent-ruby-1.1.4 conflicts with concurrent-ruby (= 1.1.3) (Gem::ConflictError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

ruby version  2.5.3

When I typed `rails new upload_app`, the following error occurred

The error is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    39: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    38: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    37: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/gems/railties-5.2.2/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    36: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    35: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    34: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    32: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    31: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    30: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    29: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    28: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    26: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    25: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    22: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    20: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    19: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    17: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    16: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    14: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    13: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
     8: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
     7: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
     6: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
     5: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
     4: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:217:in `try_activate'
     2: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:224:in `rescue in try_activate'
     1: from /Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1441:in `activate'
/Users/zhangjiachen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2332:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate concurrent-ruby-ext-1.1.3, because concurrent-ruby-1.1.4 conflicts with concurrent-ruby (= 1.1.3) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

I tried something

1. gem list | grep concurrent
   =>
   concurrent-ruby (1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.0.2)
   concurrent-ruby-ext (1.1.3)
2. gem uninstall concurrent-ruby-1.1.3
   =>
   Gem 'concurrent-ruby-1.1.3' is not installed
3. gem install concurrent-ruby-ext
   ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'concurrent-ruby-ext' (>= 0), here is why:
         Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Answer (score 13):

I solved the problem by `gem install concurrent-ruby-ext -v 1.1.5`

gem 'concurrent-ruby-ext' has always same version as gem 'concurrent-ruby'

You can refer to
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/concurrent-ruby-ext/1.1.5

```
gem list | grep concurrent
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.0.2)
concurrent-ruby-ext (1.1.5, 1.1.3)
```

Comment: I had to execute the command like this: 

`gem install concurrent-ruby-ext -v 1.1.5`

Answer (score 1):

@江洋大盗 is right, if the build system or `gemfile.lock` lock the build toolchain version, you may need to down-grade the `concurrent-ruby` and `concurrent-ruby-ext` version. Command as below.

```
$ gem uninstall concurrent-ruby -v 1.1.4

or 

$ gem uninstall concurrent-ruby-ext -v 1.1.5
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your gem with `gem update` then create your project with `rails new upload_app`